# Some VPN traffic blocked to secure endpoints

Tags: vpn, https, ipsec, opendns, strongswan

I have a VPN server (`strongswan`) used for testing that I connect to via `IKEv2` on a variety of systems (here, I tried Windows, Ubuntu, & Android), normally without issues.  This morning, I was on a train in the UK (a Transpennine Express, which use [Icomera.com](https://icomera.com)) and connected to the onboard wifi.  This is an IPv4-only network and utilises OpenDNS to block certain sites.  Unfortunately, they block stack exchange, so I connected to my VPN to *try* to bypass these restrictions.  It worked fine on some sites, such as news.bbc.co.uk, and some of twitter.com (it allowed access to https://abs.twimg.com at some addresses like `/responsive-web/web/runtime.21a6d542388d1e3e4.js` and `/responsive-web/web/main.d9a47f436e41de1a4.js` but blocked others like `/responsive-web/web/i18n-rweb/en.10f7da63e9b736204.js` and `/responsive-web/web/icon-default.3c3b224a61f8b0e54.png`).  However, other domains did not work at all; google.com and amazon.com for example.  **What could be stopping certain communication?**

`ping` and `traceroute` worked on all domains and returned valid IPs (over both v4 and v6, via the VPN - the issues still occurred if I disabled IPv6).  Connecting via `telnet` to sites via port 80 worked, but when I tried `wget` it would get stuck after a redirect (normally to https, although the below failed redirecting to a http address):

```
wget -vv -4 google.com
--2019-09-02 08:39:18--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 172.217.18.14
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|172.217.18.14|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/ [following]
--2019-09-02 08:39:18--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 216.58.205.228
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|216.58.205.228|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... ^C
```

Using `adb` (Android debug shell, connected to my mobile in case there was a peculiarity with my hardware), I tried the same - it does not have `wget` and so I used `curl`, but with the same result:

```
NB1:/ $ curl google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>

NB1:/ $ curl https://google.com
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 300191 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

If I try to SSH in to the server that the VPN is hosted on (I'm not using the key here), whilst connected to the VPN:

```
 ssh -v user@1.2.3.4
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /jkl/ssh_config
debug1: /abc/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 1.2.3.4 [1.2.3.4 port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 1.2.3.4:22 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

Then nothing, no timeout or message that it can not be authenticated etc.  Another SSH server I have access to connected fine.

The VPN server uses Cloudflare 1.1.1.1 DNS servers.  Running the command `dig +nocmd +multiline +noall +answer TXT resolver.dnscrypt.info` returns the actual resolver it appears that it is using the correct DNS configuration over the VPN:

Attempt 1:

```
resolver.dnscrypt.info. 10 IN TXT "Resolver IP: 162.158.85.239"
```

Attempt 2:

```
resolver.dnscrypt.info. 10 IN TXT "Resolver IP: 162.158.82.32"
```

Clearly it's not a DNS error as addresses are resolved, and the VPN is connecting and receiving data correctly over multiple ports (at least 22, 25, 80, 443).  **What could be stopping certain communication here?**  It's almost like there is some sort of DPI going on, and it seems related to secure communications - certain HTTPS connections, and the above SSH.  It isn't a connection issue - I ran a script pinging in the background every second, and when that failed I obviously stopped trying to diagnose the issue.

The only relevant question asking similar I can find is https://serverfault.com/questions/785363/cisco-asa-part-of-the-traffic-via-vpn-is-blocked[785363 here about a Cisco ASA device](https://serverfault.com/questions/785363/cisco-asa-part-of-the-traffic-via-vpn-is-blocked) but that's not causing the issues as they only appear on the network I was connected to.  I am assuming it's to do with the OpenDNS setup used but can't figure out how it's working.

Nothing immediate is apparent in the logs of the server in question.

For reference, when not connected to the VPN (and allowing the unsafe certificate) I see this when attempting to access stackoverflow.com in Chrome:

```
This site is blocked due to content filtering.
stackoverflow.com
Sorry, stackoverflow.com has been blocked by your network administrator.

You can still get FREE movies, TV shows and magazines through our TPE App or at tv.tpexpress.co.uk.

This site was blocked due to the following categories: Forums/Message boards

 Diagnostic Info
ACType
0
Block Type
aup
Bundle ID
640224
Domain Tagging
-
Host
block.opendns.com
IP Address
176.12.107.132
Org ID
2218188
Origin ID
72833478
Prefs
-
Query
url=8485666876808770837177808815688078&ablock&server=lon15&prefs=&tagging=&nref
Server
lon15
Time
2019-09-02 08:48:01.341364541 +0000 UTC m=+5779291.314972467
```

Comment: Have you ruled out an [MTU/MSS issue](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ForwardingAndSplitTunneling#MTUMSS-issues)?

Comment: @ecdsa I haven't looked at altering the MTU; it could be that the HTTP traffic is fragmenting and HTTPS isn't, as seen https://networkdirection.net/https-fragmentation-and-mtu/ 

I had ruled it out, as ICMP pings worked but turns out `ping` on the command line fragments!  I will update with an an answer next time I am connected to the network.